# When using Google Maps in Flutter, is there a way to return the markers currently displayed on the screen as a list?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-markers

[image]

For example, I want to be returned as a list when there are 3 markers as shown in the image above. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you wanted get the data of the markers from the map as a list?

Comment: @jabamataro there're many other markers more than 3. I want markers only that are displayed on the screen .